# Incorrect syntax near '.' when querying SQL Server from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net

I've successfully connected to our SQL Server from VBscript from an Excel file. I was able to run the following query and return the expected results, but now I'm getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '.'

The only thing I've changed was adding string breaks, ending the line with a quote, ampersand, space, hyphen to continue the query on the following line.

I've tried all the recommendations I could find on Stack Overflow,e.g. deleting and re-adding white spaces, copy/paste into a notepad to find special characters, re-adding all the '.' and manually adding CR.

Any other thoughts? Should I be using a different syntax to break up my query string?

```
SELECT 
    IM_BARCOD.BARCOD, IM_PRC.PRC_1, IM_INV.QTY_AVAIL, IM_ITEM.DESCR, 
    IM_INV.LOC_ID, IM_INV.ITEM_NO" & _
FROM 
    BCEXP.dbo.IM_BARCOD 
INNER JOIN 
    BCEXP.dbo.IM_INV ON IM_INV.ITEM_NO = IM_BARCOD.ITEM_NO 
INNER JOIN 
    BCEXP.dbo.IM_PRC ON IM_INV.ITEM_NO = IM_PRC.ITEM_NO 
INNER JOIN 
    BCEXP.dbo.IM_ITEM ON IM_INV.ITEM_NO = IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO" & _
WHERE
    (IM_ITEM.TRK_METH = 'N' AND IM_INV.LOC_ID = 'MAIN')" & _
    AND(IM_ITEM.ITEM_VEND_NO = 'OSPR' OR IM_ITEM.ITEM_VEND_NO = 'ENZEES' 
        OR IM_ITEM.ITEM_VEND_NO = 'WM')
```

Comment: you can edit your question to include the SQL code, and format it correctly

Comment: It's a better practice to use a store procedure, so you don't have to deal with long queries in VB, it's uncomfortable, and it's more easy to find errors in queries with the sql editor.

Comment: You probably need to double up your double quotes...

Comment: I had a situation like this recently where I'd copied and pasted some SQL from a web-based chat. Not until I pasted it into a hex editor did I find that there were HTML non-breaking spaces in the code. I changed those to regular spaces, and everything worked fine.

Paste the code into a hex editor and look for '0A'.

Answer (score 2):

As you have noticed, it is difficult to get SQL correct when you're using a string like that. I assume you are using an older version of Visual Studio, so one option to make the SQL more readable is to use an XML literal, like this:

```
Dim sql = <sql>
SELECT     im_barcod.barcod, 
           im_prc.prc_1, 
           im_inv.qty_avail, 
           im_item.descr, 
           im_inv.loc_id, 
           im_inv.item_nofrom bcexp.dbo.im_barcod 
inner JOIN bcexp.dbo.im_inv 
ON         im_inv.item_no=im_barcod.item_no 
INNER JOIN bcexp.dbo.im_prc 
ON         im_inv.item_no=im_prc.item_no 
INNER JOIN bcexp.dbo.im_item 
ON         im_inv.item_no=im_item.item_nowhere(im_item.trk_meth='N' 
AND        im_inv.loc_id='MAIN') 
AND       ( 
                      im_item.item_vend_no='OSPR' 
           OR         im_item.item_vend_no='ENZEES' 
           OR         im_item.item_vend_no='WM') 
</sql>.Value()
```

The name of the tag `<sql>` is not important. Your indentation may vary from that shown - I used an online SQL formatter ([Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) this time).

Now you can see that it all goes horribly wrong around

```
im_inv.item_no=im_item.item_nowhere(im_item.trk_meth='N'
```

because **there is a space missing after "item_no"**.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added spaces where it was evidently needed from your XML above and it worked! I'll be sure to use the SQL formatter in the future